# how to delete record in datagrid view when checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with a `checkbox` column, and I want to `delete` the row that is `checked` by a `delete` button. However, some other `rows` which is `unchecked` was deleted instead of the checked `row`.
I got an list object(`srv_NameList`) to store the value of each row which are used to delete the record, any value that store in that list will be delete once the button is clicked :

```
 private void dataGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        if (dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Select"))
        { 
            if (dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected == true)
            {                      
                    string srvName = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ServiceName"].Value.ToString();

                    srv_NameList.Add(srvName);                      
            }
            if (dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected == false)
            {
                string srvName_del = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ServiceName"].Value.ToString();

                if (srv_NameList.Contains(srvName_del))
                {
                    srv_NameList.Remove(srvName_del);
                }
            }
       }
 }
```

Can someone kindly tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: This kind of problems usually happen when DataGridView does not finish editing and somewhere in the code you try to remove rows. Make sure that before removing rows your DataGridView has finished editing. You can force it calling DataGridView.EndEdit().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use binded data and manipulate with data not with DataGridView.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class DtoObj
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public int Field2 { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    private BindingList<DtoObj> gridValues;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridValues = new BindingList<DtoObj>() {
            new DtoObj() { Field1 = "#1", Field2 = 1 },
            new DtoObj() { Field1 = "#2", Field2 = 2 },
            new DtoObj() { Field1 = "#3", Field2 = 3 },
            new DtoObj() { Field1 = "#4", Field2 = 4 },
        };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = gridValues;
    }

    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var objectsToRemove = gridValues.Where(o => o.IsSelected).ToList();
        foreach (var idx in objectsToRemove)
            gridValues.Remove(idx);
    }
}
```